# Showing Pop up message if error occured while creating folder [Windows Store Javascript App]

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps

I am trying to show a pop up error message to user if folder creation fails because it already exists, but `access Denied exception` is thrown on `msg.showAsync()`

```
sf.getFolderAsync(KorN_Name).then(function (kn) {
    return kn.createFolderAsync(username, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.failIfExists)
}).done(function (user) {

      //some code
        }, 
        function (error) {

                var md = Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog;
                var msg = new md("User already exists", "Ooops!");
                    msg.showAsync();
 });
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you use error handlers inside **showAsync** and let us know the entire error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It might be failing because you initialized the messageBox differently:

```
var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("User already exists","Oops!");
msg.showAsync();
```

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx) if you have not already done so.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work out. At other places in my code I can display MessageDialog but not inside that error handler. I don't know why is this so.